# Is it possible to use the VC++ 6 compiler in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compilation, legacy, visual-c++-6

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to develop my projects, and I also have installed Visual Studio 2010 - which gives me the option to use the VC++10 compiler in Visual Studio 2012 (project properties), but I also have installed Visual C++ 6 and somehow the option to use the VC++6 compiler is not present in Visual Studio 2012, how do I add this option (manually)?

Comment: I doubt that you can. Maybe via a custom Makefile project, but there is not going to be a setting that allows Visual Studio to do it.

Comment: Are there some specific reasons why you want to use the old compiler?

Comment: because I am not capable of updating 5000 VC++ 6 cpp and h files (one solution).

Comment: +1 for being a badass. Y'know, like those action heroes that blow up entire airports just to capture one bad guy hacker.

Comment: *You're doing it wrong*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit haha, nice one :p

Comment: but surely you'd want to configure VC6 so it could use the 2012 compiler... the VC6 IDE rocked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is definitely maybe. It seems quite possible, but I could not get a copy of VC 6 so I was unable to verify it. What I was able to do was to get VS 2012 to use VC 7 (VS 2002) to compile a project.

**Update:** The answer is definitely yes. The OP indicates in the comments that he was able to get VC 6 working by using this solution.

### Configuration

The way I did this was to install the following (in order of install):

**Windows 7, SP1, 32 Bit**

I chose Windows 7 because it is the earliest version of Windows that will support VS 2012. I used a 32 Bit version because VS 2002 (VC7) would not install on an x64 machine.

**Visual Studio 2002, SP1**

As I mentioned, I could not get VC6. It was no where to be found on Microsoft's site. [Bruce's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589390/where-can-i-get-visual-c-6-0#comment10166112_3589390) under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589390/where-can-i-get-visual-c-6-0) provides this helpful insight:

> Visual C++ 6.0 isn't available (including via MSDN) from Microsoft because it included the Microsoft JVM. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ff723773.aspx) for details. – [BruceCran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76093/brucecran)

After seeing the above, I figured that installing VS 2002 (VC 7) was the next best thing.

Obviously, this is where you would install VC 6, if you have a copy<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I should note, for anyone that is interested, that VC 6 is available on Ebay. If I were being paid in actual currency instead of points I would have gone the extra mile and gotten a copy of VC 6 to test.</sub>

**Visual Studio 2010, SP1**

The only reason for this is that it is a requirement for [Daffodil](http://daffodil.codeplex.com/). More on Daffodil below.

**Visual Studio 2012, Update 2**

This is a requirement from the original question.

[**Daffodil**](http://daffodil.codeplex.com/)

This is a set of configuration files that allows VS 2010 and VS 2012 to target older VC compilers.

Currently, these are the supported VC compiler versions:

- VC 8 (Visual Studio 2005)
- VC 7.1 (Visual Studio 2003)
- VC 7 (Visual Studio 2002)
- VC 6 (Visual Studio 6)

I should note that Daffodil does not officially support VS 2012 as an IDE, but it does seem to work. From the Daffodil site:

> Daffodil works fine in VS 2012 and later versions<sup>2</sup> as long as VS 2010 is also installed.

<sup>2</sup> <sub>There appears to be a debugging problem when using VS 2013 and VS 2015, as noted here: 

[Debugging information does not match, when using v60 platform toolset inside Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560149/debugging-information-does-not-match-when-using-v60-platform-toolset-inside-vis)</sub>

### Testing

To test the above I created a new C++ Win 32 console project in Visual Studio 2012. I then removed all header and cpp files from the project - these have things that are VS 2012 specific, so were not needed.  I then added a simple "hello world" file that I could use to test:

```
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
   cout << "Hello World!" << endl;   
}
```

Using the project as is (targeting VS 2012), I tried to build it and it failed.

Next, I right-clicked the project and selected *properties*. I selected *Configuration Properties* on the left side of the dialog, and then under *Platform Toolset*, on the right, I selected *v70*. You will note that there is also an option for *v60*:

[image: Test Project Properties]

I then saved the change to the project and did a build. It built an exe successfully. Just to verify that VC 7 was being used, I launched [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) during the compile:

[image: Process Monitor during Compile]

As you can see cl.exe, the compiler, is being called from the VC 7 directory.

### Final Thoughts

The original question involves compiling an existing VC 6 project. Just a couple of notes on this.

My guess is that for retargeting to work, that you will have to create a new empty project in VS 2012, and then add in all of the existing source files. The reason for doing this is that obviously the project format is different between the two versions of Visual Studio.

As I mentioned, I tested using VC 7 instead of 6.  I suppose the last step is for the OP to try all of this using VC 6. Hopefully it all works.

### Links

- [Daffodil](http://daffodil.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex
- [C++ Native Multi-Targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) for VS 2010 at the C++ Team Blog
- [VS Android](http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/) - Configuration for targeting Android using VS 2010
- [VS-Tool](https://github.com/juj/vs-tool) - Configurations for targeting various frameworks: Clang, EmScripten, MinGW, NACL, Python

Comment: You sir, are a hero. You just saved my brain and fingers from updating thousands of old cpp files.

Comment: @ThePet - glad I could help. So were you able verify that the above works with VC 6?

Comment: at least for the stuff I have - yes, probbly not too complicated solution BUT very very many source files.

Comment: @MichaelParker Did you install VS2010? If so, I am not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: My bad - I didn't have VS2010 installed. After I installed 2010 I then got error saying `TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe".`. I then added the bin path from VS8 to the executables directories. I am now getting an error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.targets(62,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515`

Comment: @MichaelParker - did you install in the order I specified above, that is, older VS versions go first?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm fairly sure the .props file included in daffodil has the wrong registry paths for VS2005 - they don't match. See discussion here: https://daffodil.codeplex.com/discussions/651841

Comment: Is there any way of working out what exactly is wrong with that CL.exe line in XML? Is it definitely correct that Microsoft.cpp.Win32.Targets file is getting used even for old versions e.g. 2005? Is it simply that the old compiler doesn't recognise some of the new switches? Or is that Targets file used as a base and then the specific platformtoolset .Targets file layered on top?

Comment: I've manually added all the platform SDK paths and the VS / VC paths into the project, this fixes the above issues. I am now getting an error at linking stage: `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'odbc32.lib'` So i'm looking into why this is needed as my project doesn't need this file.