# Debugging information does not match, when using v60 platform toolset inside Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2013, but I'm in need to develop an old project using the Visual C++ 6.0 compiler.

For this purpose, I have been using [Daffodil](https://daffodil.codeplex.com/) with no problem on Windows 8.1 for a while. 
(You can read more how to use the VC++ 6 compiler in newer Visual Studio versions in this StackOverflow question: [Is it possible to use the VC++ 6 compiler in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029762/is-it-possible-to-use-the-vc-6-compiler-in-visual-studio-2012))

Now I got a new Windows 10 machine, where I reinstalled Visual Studio 6, 2010, 2013 and Daffodil.

Using v60 build tools (Visual C++ 6.0 compiler), project gets compiled fine.

However, when I try to debug, VS says that "debugging information does not match", and I am unable to set breakpoints etc., but:

- PDB file is there, same folder and name of debug executable;
- Application built in Debug mode, with debug information enabled;
- Debugger works fine when using Visual Studio 2010 or 2013 build tools;
- Debugger works fine if opening the project inside Visual C++ 6 IDE.

I tried reinstalling all Visual Studio versions as well as Daffodil, but didn't solve. 
Any clue what could the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I actually found a working solution!

**for VS 2013:**
Enable "Native Edit and Continue" 
under Tools->Options->Debugging->Edit and Continue

**for VS 2015:**
Enable "Use Native Compatibility Mode"
under Tools->Options->Debugging->General

Comment: +I - the error message I received was "Binary was not built with debug information". This fixed it!