# How to compile & debug a Visual C++ 6.0 code in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'v a big project writing in Visual C++ 6.0.

It's painful to develop in the Visual C++ 6.0 environment, so I want to use VS2019 environment with Visual C++ 6.0 compiler.

I tried this solution [Daffodil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029762/is-it-possible-to-use-the-vc-6-compiler-in-visual-studio-2012) in my machine it works ! but when i test it in the machine where the project is located I lost configuration propreties when I select v60 platform toolset.

[image: v60]

do you have any idea to resolve this or any other solution to use 6.0 C++ compiler in VS2019

Comment: On Daffodil's website: `Daffodil works fine in VS 2012 and later versions as long as VS 2010 is also installed.` So, I suggest that you could try to install VS2010.

Comment: @BarrnetChou VS2010 is already installed. but it doesn't work

Comment: Could  you tell me what operating system the project is running on?  It may be because the corresponding .net framework is not installed.

Comment: @BarrnetChou both are in windows 10, I checked for the .NET freamwork and it is installed int the root `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\`

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the computer where your project is located. It is recommended that you reinstall VS on that computer.